# Why does TFramedScrollBox always return number of controls as 2 only in FMX?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, scrollbox

I have to know number of controls placed inside a TFramedScrollBox control container.

When I use the code `TFramedScrollBox.ControlsCount`. It always return the value `2`. Why?

I want to use the `for loop` and iterate through each control and set a few properties. As the number of controls returned is always `2` I am not able to iterate through each control contained inside TFramedScrollBox.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: The documentation links to the Content property

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The FMX `TFramedScrollBox` (as well as `TScrollBox`) has a property `Content: TScrollContent` which holds the added controls. Use `Content.Controls` to list the controls.

For example:

```
for i := 0 to FramedScrollBox1.Content.ControlsCount-1 do
  Memo1.Lines.Add(FramedScrollBox1.Content.Controls[i].Name);
```

Edit:

To answer the question "why `TFramedScrollBox.ControlsCount` always returns 2?:

The two components indicated by `TFramedScrollBox.ControlsCount` and which can be accessed via `TFramedScrollBox.Controls` are a `TLayout` and a `TScrollContent`. The latter being the `Content` that holds the child controls.

Comment: This only answers 1/2 of the question asked. It provides a solution, but it would also be helpful to address the WHY about `ControlsCount` always being 2, and what those 2 controls actually are.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Added answer for the first half of the question.